# Let $\Omega $ countable. Why the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the power set?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega $ a countable set. Why the Borel $\sigma
$-algebra is the power set of $\Omega $? Just take $\Omega =\{1,...,6\}$ Does it has even sense to talk about Borel set in $\Omega $ ? What could be an open ?

Comment: Yes of course ! $\Omega $ has the discrete topology ! So every subset is open, in particular the Borel $\sigma -$algebra is the power set (since all element of $\mathcal P(\Omega )$ is open).

Comment: @Surb : I don't get the point ! It looks very un-natural to have open set in discrete set. Suppose you right. What is the motivation to have a Borel $\sigma -$algebra in a countable set ? Why do the want open set ? It makes no sense. Just take the power set, and finish, no ? Why do they want the Borel $\sigma -$algebra ?

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra depends on a topology you select. If you start with the anti-discrete one... Anyway, you know all the answers yourself.

Comment: @metamorphy : I don't understand the aim of your answer...

Comment: On the other hand, for any $T_1$ topology you choose on a countable set, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra does end up being the power set, since any subset is a countable union of singletons and all singletons are closed.

Comment: In fact, I guess even $T_0$ would be sufficient: for any $x,y$, either there is an open set $D_{x,y}$ containing $x$ but not $y$, or a closed set containing $x$ but not $y$.  Then $\bigcap_{y \ne x} D_{x,y} = \{ x \}$ is Borel, and from here you can proceed as before.

Comment: @user601023 : Open set are important to gives regularity to measure especially to define Radon measure.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: But this doesn't answer my question : Who care about the Borel $\sigma -$algebra for a countable set since it's the power set ? Why do we need open set in finite set for example ? Because it really look not useful... just take the power set, and finish ! (I know that power set and Borel $\sigma -$algebra are the same, but why thinking about Borel $\sigma -$algebra) ?

Comment: @Surb: I don't understand your answer... sorry !

Comment: @user601023 I'm not sure if this is still relevant but I'll put this out there for potential future readers. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a countable set Ω is not necessarily the $\mathcal P(\Omega)$. It is only $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ if you choose your topology on $\Omega$ to be the Discrete Topology. 

On the other hand, if you choose your topology to be the Chaotic Topology (i.e. $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ ), then your Borel $\sigma$-algebra of
$\Omega$ is $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ which is not $\mathcal P(\Omega)$.